# Insert column from other table into another

Tags: mysql

I need to add the column "date" from other table into another table in my db.

First table:

```
id       date
 1      01/01/2010
 2      02/01/2010
```

Second table (where I need to insert "date"):

```
id     date
 1
 2
```

The second table is where I need to insert "date" from the first table, where both ids are the same.

What I have, at the moment, is this query that return syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 A (date)
SELECT date FROM Table1 B
WHERE A.id = B.id
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you need assistance writing a query, you need to first attempt something yourself. Please update your question with the attempt you've made and where you're struggling.

Comment: Thanks... I`ve just updated it.

Comment: It would also help if you include the syntax error that you're receiving.

Comment: Although you want an UPDATE as shown in Gordon's answer below for this issue, for your future knowledge, in MySQL you can do a SELECT as a subquery to an INSERT - you put the SELECT inside ()'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an `update`:

```
update table2 a join
       table1 b
       on a.id = b.id
    set a.date = b.date;
```

You need to be sure that the column exists in the second table.  If it doesn't you can add it in using something like `alter table table2 add column date date`.